# spudsoft emitter issue while using with Birt engine

Tags: java, birt-emitter

In my java code, I am trying to export Birt report master page header, which is an image using spudsoft emitter but it's not getting exported but if the header is a text element it does get exported.

I tried setting ExcelEmitter.StructuredHeader like below but no luck options.setOption("ExcelEmitter.StructuredHeader ", true);

Below is the spudsoft documentation where its mentioned that setting structuredheader to true will let master page header and footer rendered into the Excel sheet at the top and the bottom of the sheet
https://bitbucket.org/yaytay/spudsoft-birt-excel-emitters/wiki/UserProperties

I am using opensource Birt engine 4.6
Please ask if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

I did some troubleshooting and realized that the images do not export only for the Master page header otherwise it gets export. 
I also saw a weird behavior like the exported image was different than the one I added in my report!! 
[Image I added to my report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0lOL.png)
[Image got Exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1ogA.png)
I also found that the image issue I have is a bug in the Spudsoft emitter.
[Here is the bug link](https://bitbucket.org/yaytay/spudsoft-birt-excel-emitters/issues/151/image-in-header-for-excel)